# Keep an item selected in drop down navigation menu after exiting application

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

If the user were to select an item from the drop down navigation menu, it appears as selected only until the application closes. Then, on reopening the app, it displays the first item as selected. How can I keep an item permanently selected until the user changes it even after the activity closes? FYI There is only one activity in my application.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.student.connect;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * current dropdown position.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private WebView student_zangle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setTitle("  ");
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                                "Select a District",
                                "Clovis Unified",
                                "Claremont Unified",
                                "San Diego Unified",
                                "Pleasanton Unified",
                                "San Juan Unified", }), this);
    }

    /**
     * Backward-compatible version of {@link ActionBar#getThemedContext()} that
     * simply returns the {@link android.app.Activity} if
     * <code>getThemedContext</code> is unavailable.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current dropdown position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id)
    {
        WebView student_zangle = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.student_zangle);
        student_zangle.setWebViewClient( new YourWebClient());
        WebSettings settings = student_zangle.getSettings();
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        if ( position == 0 )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select a District from the Menu Above", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if ( position == 1 )
        {
            student_zangle.loadUrl("https://zangleweb01.clovisusd.k12.ca.us/studentconnect/");
            student_zangle.zoomOut();
            student_zangle.zoomOut();
            student_zangle.zoomOut();
        }
        else if ( position == 2 )
        {
            student_zangle.loadUrl("http://studentconnect.cusd.claremont.edu/");
        }
        else if ( position == 3 )
        {
            student_zangle.loadUrl("https://zangle.sandi.net/studentconnect/");
        }
        else if ( position == 4 )
        {
            student_zangle.loadUrl("https://sis.pleasanton.k12.ca.us/StudentPortal/");
        }
        else if ( position == 5 )
        {
            student_zangle.loadUrl("https://sis.sanjuan.edu/studentportal");
        }

        student_zangle.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY); 
        settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");

        student_zangle.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        { 
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, 
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
            { 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                intent.setType("application/x-rar-compressed"); 
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
                startActivity(intent); 
            } 
        });
        return true;
    }


    @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
      }

    private class YourWebClient extends WebViewClient {     
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("mailto"))
            {
                String mail = url.replaceFirst("mailto:", "");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mail );
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;            
            }
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to store your selected position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` for this case.

```
  //write your selected position in preferences when the user clicks the DropDown menu
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  preferences.edit().putInt("selectedPosition", selectedItemIndex).commit();
```

When the user returns to the Activity (launching the app again), you have to read the value from Preferences, like this:

```
int position = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("selectedPosition",0);
```

Then just select your dropdown menu item programatically.

The SharedPreferences data is kept even when the app closes. So you can trust it because it's persistent data and does not depend on your App state.

Note that your Preferences will be empty if the user unninstalls the app or clears the app data.

Comment: So I could write the position in preferences in my onNavigationItemSelected() method after the user selects an item, and then read the value in onCreate? Or will I have to read it in another method such as onPause or onResume?